# Powershell check if object values contain a $null

Tags: powershell, object, null

I want to check whether a powershell object contains any null values. If it does, then it should return a $true

For example

```
$tags=@{'Artist'='Madonna';`
        'Title'='Like a Prayer';`
        'Genre'=$null; }
```

How can I test that $tags contains a null value?

Comment: Well you will need to be more specific, checking if there is a null in a hashtable could be as simple as `$tags.ContainsValue($null)` but I'll assume you're also looking to check if it contains an empty string and I'll also assume, since you're talking about a powershell obejct, `$tags` is not actually a hashtable but a `pscustomobject` instead.

Comment: Great, that worked. .containsvalue($null) gave me the outcome i required. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.ContainsValue` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.hashtable.containsvalue?view=net-7.0#system-collections-hashtable-containsvalue(system-object)):

```
$tags.ContainsValue($null)
```

Using a [containment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) would also work:

```
$tags.Values -contains $null
$null -in $tags.Values
```